# Textbox over image in slider gallery in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

I made a slider but I would like to have text on every single picture.
The images should have a transparent white text box in the center in which there is a text. I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bootstrap carousel is what you're looking for then this should help

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/5783556cdd0895a96d8b47b9-480/pikachu-pokemon-nintendo.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Pokemon</h3>
          <p>PokemonPokemonPokemon</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/caxndn8emf4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>PokemonPokemon</h3>
          <p>PokemonPokemonPokemonPokemon</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.serebii.net/ultrasunultramoon/ichooseyoucappikachu.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>PokemonPokemonPokemon</h3>
          <p>PokemonPokemonPokemonPokemonPokemon</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I was looking for